# how can i load the contents of an xml file at a url into a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i load the contents of an xml file at a url into a string?

eg there is an xml file at http://www.example.com/test.xml

I want the text of the xml to be assigned to a string.
How can i do that using c#?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that the fact it's XML is irrelevant - just download it as a string:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string text = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon (+1). To load async, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038711/how-do-i-load-an-xml-file-and-read-from-it-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Other way to get the xml file is through HttpRequest, then you can parse the XML, if that's what you need:
[previous question on the matter (with code sample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443858/reading-xml-from-aspx-web-page)